# Pointer to vector in a struct C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am getting a few crashes related to the fact that I use a vector in my struct that may have to use about 6000 elements. Here is my struct:

```
struct Students 
{
char* names;
std::vector<int> scores;
};
```

Is there a way to make it so my vector is not causing my struct to cause an error. Here is my calling code.

```
while(scores.hasNext())
{
    students[current_student].scores.push_back(grade);
}
```

My question: if this is a problem with size allocation of a vector within a struct, could I declare a pointer to a vector and deference my vector instead of having it actually in the struct?

Grades is just an integer.

Comment: You haven't got a "pointer to vector in a struct". The code as posted makes no sense.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: more infomation needed.  What is the type of `students` and `grade`? Give the error message too.

Comment: Sorry. I just realized that I didn't formulate my whole question. I updated it.

Comment: What language are you asking about? In C++ there `hasNext` is not used in the standard at all, so the `while` condition is either bogus or you are talking about iterators in some other language (Java?) or about a hand rolled  piece of code that you are not showing.

Comment: You have a pointer to char not vector, that needs to be a `string`. :)

Comment: @David Yes, the hasNext is a function in one of my classes which lets me know if there are still grades to read in.

Comment: I suspect your question is missing quite a lot of logic which may be relevant. What is scores a type of? - wheres it from? What sort of error are you actually getting? is it always at the same place? All these facts can help you debug the issue, as it is I can't be sure where your error is....

Comment: My main question: is there any reason a vector in a struct would cause an error? Even if it has a lot of elements? If there is a possibility for a problem, could I do a pointer to a vector in the struct?

Comment: @Tarus: A `vector` in a `struct` is 100% fine. It's not the problem of your code. And the maximum size of such vector is virtually limited by the amount of memory you have (modulo heap fragmentation).

Comment: As your struct looks, your vector is unlikely to be the one causing a problem. Post the other code asked for by others here, cause the error is bound to be there somewhere

Comment: I wouldn't have  thought there would be a problem with the vector if you didn't exceed vector::max_size, or if you were maybe multithreading or something.
Of course you could do a pointer to a vector in a struct, yet - since I'm really really unsure of what your actual problem is - I have no idea if that would help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remind me of a similar problem someone here met before. As there is no enough information provided for the rest of your code, I just make a guess here.

Obviously `students` is an array of structure `Students`. Assuming it's allocated on the heap, if you do that using `malloc`, it won't work properly because **malloc won't properly initialize the members in the structure**. Especially, here `scores` is a non-POD object and it needs properly constructed by calling its constructor.

```
// the member in your structure is not initialized
students = (struct Students*) malloc(10 * sizeof(Students));

// oops.. scores is not initialized
students[0].scores.push_back(100);
```

To solve it, you need call `new` instead. It'll properly initialize members by calling their constructors.

```
// ok
students = new Students[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get some error from `vector`'s code in this line

```
students[current_student].scores.push_back(grade);
```

it doesn't mean that the problem is with the vector. what it does mean is that you access invalid memory (not initialized or not allocated). Probably `current_student` is out-of-bounds of `students`, or you allocated `students` by a call to `malloc` instead of `new`.

Your question cannot be answered without you giving more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should't think of `struct` as weird things that need special precautions.  [They are equivalent to class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/classes-and-objects.html#faq-7.9)

Then, as stated in the comments, you should add real code, because if you really do :

```
while(scores.hasNext())
{
  students[current_student].scores.push_back(grade);
}
```

then you will keep on adding elements to your vector (if `hasNext()` works as it sounds) until you get a `std::bad_alloc()`

And finally, don't worry about the size of your vector : a `std::vector` is basically already a pointer to a vector in the heap. Your struct will remain "small" not matter how "fat" your vector becomes.